# python csv question

Tags: python, csv

i'm just testing out the csv component in python, and i am having some trouble with it.

I have a fairly standard csv string, and the default options all seems to fit with my test, but the result shouldn't group 1, 2, 3, 4 in a row and 5, 6, 7, 8 in a row?

Thanks a lot for any enlightenment provided!

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> c = "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n"
>>> test = csv.reader(c)
>>> for t in test:
...     print t
... 
['1']
['', '']
[' ']
['2']
['', '']
[' ']
['3']
['', '']
[' ']
['4']
[]
[' ']
['5']
['', '']
[' ']
['6']
['', '']
[' ']
['7']
['', '']
[' ']
['8']
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Note that I closed this one instead of the newer one because the answers to the other are useful here, but not so much the other way around. This still gets the badge of originality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

csv.reader expects an iterable. You gave it `"1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n"`; iteration produces characters. Try giving it ["1, 2, 3, 4\n", "5, 6, 7, 8\n"] -- iteration will produce lines.

Answer (score 3):

`csv.reader` takes an iterable or iterator returning lines, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader). You're passing it a string, which is an iterable returning single characters.

So, use `csv.reader(c.splitlines())` or similar constructs!

Answer (score 2):

test = csv.reader(c.split('\n'))

Answer (score 2):

To make it more file-like try this.

```
import StringIO
c= StringIO.StringIO( "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n" )
```

Now c looks like a file.  A file is what you use with csv most (if not all) of the time.