# Python CSV parsing not returning proper rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and having issues with the CSV parser. Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import csv


u = urllib2.urlopen(r'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=nab')
data = u.read()

reader = csv.reader(data)

for row in reader:
    print row
```

Yahoo returns this raw csv:

```
"Apple Inc.",482.09,482.00
"Google Inc.",877.20,876.94
"Microsoft Corpora",33.34,33.33
```

I want to parse this and create a simple JSON object with 3 fields:
Ticker, Bid, Offer

But the data comes in from that csv.reader() like so:

```
['Apple Inc.']
['', '']
['4']
['8']
['2']
['.']
['5']
['5']
['', '']
['4']
['8']
['2']
['.']
['4']
['8']
[]
[]
['Google Inc.']
['', '']
['8']
['7']
['6']
['.']
['2']
['4']
['', '']
['8']
['7']
['6']
['.']
['1']
['0']
[]
[]
['Microsoft Corpora']
['', '']
['3']
['3']
['.']
['2']
['9']
['', '']
['3']
['3']
['.']
['2']
['8']
[]
[]
```

It seems to be breaking the rows on each number. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python csv question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083364/python-csv-question)  (though this question has a more useful title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse `u` directly into the reader:

```
import urllib2
import csv

u = urllib2.urlopen(r'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=nab')

reader = csv.reader(u)

for row in reader:
    print row
```

The problem is that `csv.reader` accepts an iterable of lines. When you pass it a string, it thinks each character is a line. In fact, the reason it doesn't just give single-character elements is due the the quotation marks.

`u` is already an iterable of lines, so it's fine to just pass in.

Comment: This is perhaps even better than my answer since the object returned by `urlopen` iterates by line--calling `readlines()` is unnecessary overhead in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` factory takes as its first argument a list or other iterable iterable of lines, not the full string with line breaks in it (which it will just iterate over by character).  Use `data = u.readlines()` instead of `data = u.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> The so-called CSV (Comma Separated Values) format is the most common import and export format for spreadsheets and databases. There is no “CSV standard”, so the format is operationally defined by the many applications which read and write it. The lack of a standard means that subtle differences often exist in the data produced and consumed by different applications. These differences can make it annoying to process CSV files from multiple sources. Still, while the delimiters and quoting characters vary, the overall format is similar enough that it is possible to write a single module which can efficiently manipulate such data, hiding the details of reading and writing the data from the programmer.

try to make your own csv and see if it works, if yes then there is something different about their csv format.

Comment: The format of this file is parses fine with the default settings.  The problem is that they're not passing in line-by-line iterator as required by `csv.reader`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are right. I am not sure since I never used python.